# How to adjust fractional scaling in Settings/Displays in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using keyboard shortcut or command line?

Tags: 20.04, windows, shortcut-keys, vmware, scaling

I am using 125% fractional scaling in Settings/Displays in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It works great!

However, VMware player 16.2.1 (with enabling 'Accelerate 3D graphics') Windows 10 client can't display full screen mode on two physical monitors correctly in Ubuntu host with 125% fractional scaling. VMware Windows client works great when Ubuntu host is 100% fractional scaling.

I tried to find a solution for the problem above but no luck. I think a workaround is to change fractional scaling as 100% in the Ubuntu Setting before launching WMware and change back 125% after closing VMware. In order to adjust fractional scaling efficiently, I wonder if there is any way to adjust fractional scaling in Settings/Displays in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using keyboard shortcut or command line?

Comment: Although not being an answer to your question, this CLI application might do the trick:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/01/more-scaling-levels-ubuntu/